# How can I calculate the distance between two points along a complex path?

Tags: matlab

I have a set of lines that define a W shape. On each line I have then defined a set of `M` points that separated by a fixed width. Now I'd like to calculate the `MxM` matrix of distances where the value of `(i,j)` contains the `along-the-path-distance` between the points `i` and `j`.

Here is an of the `along-the-path-distance` between two points.

[image]

How can I calculate this distance in Matlab?

Comment: A general solution is found by using shortest-path algorithms. I suggest you take a look on this excellent blog about doing just that with existing functions in matlab: http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2011/12/13/exploring-shortest-paths-part-5/

Comment: @GuntherStruyf yea I've read that post but it seems a bit overkill as I have the actual point and line definitions instead of a raw image. So instead of doing the image analysis for each set of points I think I should be able to calculate it exactly. Thanks for the link though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It mostly comes down to whether a simple algorithm that only works for this sort of shape is sufficient or if you'll need to also find the distance with different complex paths. If it's just this shape then it's rather trivial

Here the yHoriz is the y value of the horizontal line that connects the vertical lines and x and y I and J are the x and y values of the points i and j.

```
distance= abs(yI - yHoriz) + abs(xJ-xI) + abs(yJ - yHoriz)
```

You would need to check if the the points are on the same vertical line and just find the difference in their y values instead of the above value if they are on the same line.

Comment: thanks, I was totally over thinking this problem trying to come up with a more general solution when i'll really never need one.

Comment: This works except for when the two points are on the same vertical line. I have to calculate the x distance first and then compute the y distance differently based upon the value of x.  I've edited your answer to reflect this.